# Find all functions if $f(x^2)+f(xy)=f(x)f(y)+yf(x)+xf(x+y)$ for all $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$.

Tags: contest-math, functional-equations

Let $\mathbb{R}$ denote the set of real numbers. Find all functions $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that
$$f(x^2)+f(xy)=f(x)f(y)+yf(x)+xf(x+y)$$
for all $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$.

---

If we put $x=0$ and mark $a=f(0)$ we get $$2a=af(y)+ya$$
so for $a\ne 0$ we get $f(y)=2-y$ for all $y$. Now say $a=0$, so $f(0)=0$. Leting $y=0$ we get $\boxed{f(x^2) = xf(x)}$. If we put this in starting equation we get $$xf(x) +f(xy)=f(x)f(y)+yf(x)+xf(x+y)\;\;\;\;(*)$$

From boxed equation we see that $f$ is odd:
Edit
$$-xf(-x) = f((-x)^2)= f(x^2)=xf(x) \implies f(-x)=-f(x)$$

Leting $y=-x$ in $(*)$ we get: $$xf(x)-f(x^2) =-f(x)^2-xf(x)\implies \underline{xf(x)= -f(x)^2}$$

---

**Edit** 28. 06. 2022

Let $G$ be a set of all real $x$ such that $f(x)=-x$. Clearly $0\in G$.

Suppose exists $x,y\in G$ so that $x \neq 0$. Here we can assume both $x,y$ are nonnegative, since $f(-x)=-f(x) = -(-x)$. Then we have $$-x^2+f(xy) =xf(x+y)$$ Then we have 4 possibilities:

- $f(xy)=0$ and $f(x+y)=0$ so $-x^2=0$ which is not true.
- $f(xy)=0$ and $f(x+y)=-x-y$ so $-x^2=-x^2-xy$ which is true only if $y=0$.
- $f(xy)=-xy$ and $f(x+y)=0$ so $-x(x+y)=0$ which is not true since $x,y$ are nonegative and $x\ne0$.
- $f(xy)=-xy$ and $f(x+y)=-x-y$ so $-x^2-xy=x(-x-y)$ which is true.

So if $x,y\in G$ then also $x+y\in G$ wich means $G$ is aditive subgroup of $(\mathbb{R},+)$ if$|G|\geq 2$.

What to do now? Is this $G$ usefull at all?

Comment: $x f(x) = f(x)^2 \iff (x-f(x)) f(x) = 0 \iff f(x) = x \vee f(x) = 0$

Comment: From that what you wrote we can deduce that $f$ is for some $x$ equal $0$ and for othe to $x$ it self. What can I do with that.

Comment: I can show that $f(x)=0$ for all $x\in\mathbb{Q}$, but I don't know yet how to extend to $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: From $f(x)=x \vee f(x)=0$ we see that there is some set $N \subset \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x) = 0$ when $x \in N$ and $f(x) = x$ when $x \not\in N.$

Comment: According to @Batominovski we have $\mathbb{Q} \subseteq N.$

Comment: Yeah, so we have ininite number of solution or we can say something more for $N$.?

Comment: I know this is an old question, but for the benefit of future readers, there is an algebraic mistake on the last line: the $xf(x)$ terms don't cancel. The conclusion should be $-f(x)^2 = 2xf(x) -f(x^2) = xf(x) = f(x^2)$. The minus makes quite a bit of difference, completely invalidating the simple logic of the accepted answer, which took your conclusion for granted without noticing the error.

Comment: @NickPavlov I made some edit, can you read it please?

Comment: I don't know about the subgroup; my line of thought was very different. Write the original equation with $x$ and $y$ switched, then subtract the result from the original (an anti-symmetrization procedure of sorts), then use the properties you already have, and you can get that it must be an additive function.

Answer (score 2):

Let $P(x,y)$ be the assertion that
$$f(x^2)+f(xy)=f(x)\,f(y)+y\,f(x)+x\,f(x+y)\,.$$
If $f(0)=0$, then we already know that
$$f(x^2)=x\,f(x)=\big(f(x)\big)^2\text{ and }f(-x)=-f(x)$$
for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

The condition $P(x,x)$ implies that
$$2\,x\,f(x)=f(x^2)+f(x^2)=\big(f(x)\big)^2+x\,f(x)+x\,f(2x)=2\,x\,f(x)+x\,f(2x)\,.$$
Thus, $x\,f(2x)=0$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.  That is,
$$f(2x)=0\text{ for all }x\neq 0\,.$$
Since $f(0)=0$, we conclude that
$$f(x)=0\text{ for all }x\in\mathbb{R}\,.$$

Thus, there are two possible solutions. First, as the OP has discovered, we have $f(x)=2-x$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.  Second, we have the trivial solution $f\equiv 0$.

Comment: There are two possible values of $f(0)$: $f(0)=2$ and $f(0)=0$.  The solution $f(x)=2-x$ corresponds to $f(0)=2$.  In my answer, I only dealt with $f(0)=0$, since the OP has completed the case $f(0)=2$.  The condition $f(x^2)=\big(f(x)\big)^2$  is only true under the assumption that $f(0)=0$.

Comment: Unfortunately, one of the OP's conclusions - which was taken for granted here - is invalidated by an algebraic error. So this is, ultimately, incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

$x f(x) = f(x)^2$ says either $f(x) = 0$ or $f(x) = x$.  Now if $f(x)=x$ and $f(y)=y$, $f(x^2) = x f(x) = x^2$, and your equation says
$$  x^2 + f(xy) = 2 x y + x f(x+y) $$
But this  does not work with any combination of $f(x+y)=0$ or $f(x+y)=x+y$ and $f(xy)=0$ or $f(x+y)=xy$ unless $x=0$ or $y=0$ or $x=y$
or $x=2y$.  Ultimately the conclusion should be  that $f(x)=0$.

Comment: So you suposed that there are two values for $f$ that it takes it to it self and then proved that this is impossibile?

Comment: Didn't actually prove anything.

Answer (score 0):

As other answers have proven, $f(x) = 0$, and $2-x$ are solutions. But there is another.

If we assume that $f(x) \ne 2-x$ then $f(0) = 0$.

Rearranging the given equation, we get:

$f(xy) - f(x)f(y) = yf(x) + x f(x+y) - f(x^2) = xf(y) + yf(x+y)-f(y^2)$

Where the final equation was obtained by swapping $x\leftrightarrow y$ (The L.H.S. is symmetric in x, y).

Taking $y=-x$ we see from the right part of the equation that $f(-x) = -f(x)$ i.e. $f$ is odd.

Looking at the left side of the equation, we then get $f(x)^2 = - x f(x)$ (!!! this sign seems to be reversed in other "solutions"!!!)

Assuming that $f$ is not identically zero, then $f(x) = -x$, which is indeed a solution.

So the three solutions are $f(x) = \{0, 2-x, -x\}$.